# "The '<' operator is reserved for future use" in PowerShell

Tags: linux, powershell

I'm trying to run the following command on powershell:

```
C:\Users\amalj\OneDrive\Desktop\CS4023\labs\week07/findvals -r 5.6 -t 230.0 < C:\Users\amalj\OneDrive\Desktop\CS4023\labs\week07/mat.2x3
```

And it's showing up:

```
    At line:1 char:77
+ ... neDrive\Desktop\CS4023\labs\week07\findvals -r 5.6 -t 230.0 <C:\Users ...
+                                                                 ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As it is part of a lab you might be able to change your findvars to simply accept an input file.

You could use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2) and the `-RedirectStandardInput` flag to make it work in a similar manner.

Another option might be to inverse your call and use the PowerShell [Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.2). An example of this would be to use `Get-Content` to read the file and pass the contain along using the pipeline to your findvars. Keep in mind that you might need to use `-Raw` depending on how your findvars operates.